# Heading width are wrong if they are defined in a class

Tags: documentclass-writing

I created a new class based on the book class. In this class I use the package fancyhdr in order to define some heading content.

In my document, I load my new class and then I set the page dimensions with the geometry package. The problem is that the heading do not span all the page width. I did already observed that for example if you defined heading before you load geometry package. But here, as heading are defined in the class I cannot load geometry before. How can I fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: You could (and probably should) add `\Requirepackage{geometry}` to your class, and then set the page dimensions in the class.

Comment: load `geometry` first and then `fancyhdr`  in your class. The margins can then be set in your document.

Comment: Actually it does not work. Maybe I forgot to remove margins from the cls file when I have tested it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reset `\headwidth` or let fancyhdr recalculate `\headwidth` by (re)setting the offsets:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{right}
%\AtBeginDocument{\let\headwidth\textwidth}
\AtBeginDocument{\fancyhfoffset{0pt}} % comment to see the difference
\usepackage[margin=6cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\section{blub}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, I just add `\AtBeginDocument{\let\headwidth\textwidth}` at the end of my class file.